# How to iterate Set in nested way like array in CPP

Tags: c++, loops

I want to perform this kind of operation using a `set`:

```
set<int> s;
for (int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
    for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++){
        cout << s[j];
    }
}
```

Comment: **You can't**   do this with set. You have to do use range-based for loop like `for(const int &element: s){cout<<element<<endl;}`

Comment: Range based loops or iterators.

Comment: Why do you want to go through each element many times?

Comment: Can you tell me the process for the second loop

Comment: You've stated what you want. That's not a question. Even if you think people should be able to guess what you intend to ask, please write out your question. Search engines function better when they don't have to read minds, and the goal of Stack Overflow is to have a *searchable* collection of questions and answers. (Besides, forcing yourself to write out what you mean sometimes is enough to reveal the answer, or at least to refine the question. Especially if you put in the effort to be clear.)

Comment: If your goal is to do this O(N^2) iteration because you're trying to implement some kind of inefficient sorting algorithm, be aware that `std::set` is by definition _ordered_, so if you walk through it with a single range-based loop (or use standard iterators) then you will visit the elements in sorted order.  If your goal is to have index-based random access to the values, then you're using the wrong container.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/jcrMWEszT

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Oh, Are you  looking for this.

What you want to achieve is can be done with the help of C++ Iterators.

```
set<int> st = {4, 3, 5, 6};
set<int>::iterator it1, it2;
for (it1 = st.begin(); it1 != st.end();) {
    for (it2 = it1++; it2 != st.end(); it2++) {
        cout << (*it2) << space;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Output

```
3 4 5 6 
4 5 6 
5 6 
6
```

Read more about them from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterators-c-stl/).

Comment: This is not equivalent to what they are asking.  Note the initial value of `it2` versus the initial value of `j`.

Comment: I get what you are talking about. I posted it so just in case it can help him.